# Find all natural numbers $n$ such that ${(n+1)}^{1/2}-{(n-1)}^{1/2}$ is rational

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all natural numbers n such that ${(n+1)}^{1/2}-{(n-1)}^{1/2}$ is a rational number
I think there wouldn't be any natural number as the square of a rational number is rational, which is not possible in this case. Am I correct please help me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n-1} \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n-1})^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$.  Since $(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n-1})^2 = 2n - 2\sqrt{n^2-1}$, we have $\sqrt{n^2-1}\in\mathbb{Q}$.

But the only two consecutive squares are $0$ and $1$, so the only natural $n$ for which $\sqrt{n^2-1}$ is rational is $n=1$, which fails to satisfy the original condition.